# Why is this for iteration variable still around after the for loop?

Tags: c#

I have been reading some C# interview questions and found a permutation of a popular one about delegates the code of which puzzles me.

The question was:

> Predict the output of the code below.

```
delegate void Iterator();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Iterator> iterators = new List<Iterator>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        iterators.Add(delegate { Console.WriteLine(i); });
    }

    foreach (var iterator in iterators)
    {
        iterator();
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

The normal version of this question I've seen declares the `i` variable before the `for` loop, thus making it method-wide and from there it's easy to see why [the output is "15" 15 times.](https://rextester.com/ELSP68883)

However when I debugged the code the `i` variable is out of scope in the `foreach` loop and does not exist, anymore. Yet, when I step into the `iterator()` method it exists for the `Console.WriteLine(i)` line.

This I cannot understand.

Comment: The variable `i` is ‘captured’ by the delegate. Note the the best answer to the “predict the output” question is to ask in return “in which version of c#?” - see https://medium.com/@Coder_HarryLee/how-to-capture-a-variable-in-c-and-not-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-d169aa161aa6

Comment: @MartinSmith The OP was describing a different version which has the `i` variable declared before the for loop. I know the output is the same but your example doesn't reflect what the OP was describing in that paragraph.

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx

Comment: @ahmed they are describing that different version on the grounds that it returns the same result IMO. so it seems a reasonable place to hang a link off showing the result in this case.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed, indeed as Mr. Smith pointed out, I was just mentioning a variation of this question, where the answer is quite more obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To put it very simply, closures allow you to encapsulate some
>   behaviour, pass it around like any other object, and still have access
>   to the context in which they were first declared. This allows you to
>   separate out control structures, logical operators etc from the
>   details of how they're going to be used. The ability to access the
>   original context is what separates closures from normal objects,
>   although closure implementations typically achieve this using normal
>   objects and compiler trickery.
>
> In your example you've only actually declared a single `i` variable -
>   so that same `i` variable is captured by all the Action instances. The
>   result is the number 15 being printed on every line. o "fix" the code
>   to make it display the output most people would expect (i.e. 0 to 14)
>   we need to introduce an extra variable inside the loop:

```
delegate void Iterator();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Iterator> iterators = new List<Iterator>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        int copy = i;
        iterators.Add(delegate { Console.WriteLine(copy); });
    }

    foreach (var iterator in iterators)
    {
        iterator();
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

> Each time we go through the loop we're said to get a different
>   instance of the `copy` variable - each Action captures a different
>   variable. This makes perfect sense if you look at what the compiler's
>   actually doing behind the scenes, but initially it flies in the face
>   of the intuition of most developers (including me).

[via](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

The compiler translates your code to the following code, this is why `i` variable is not out of scope.

```
private delegate void Iterator();

[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class CompGenCls
{
    public int i;

    internal void CompGenFunc()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Iterator> iterators = new List<Iterator>();
    CompGenCls obj = new CompGenCls();
    obj.i = 0;
    for (; obj.i < 15; obj.i++)
    {
        iterators.Add(obj.CompGenFunc);
    }

    foreach (Iterator item in iterators)
    {
        item();
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: You are concentrating on a scenario I only *mentioned*, instead of explaining the issue in detail.